# Access special Layout from outside of a Component (NativeScript + Vue)

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

my app consists of:

6 components in component folder,

3 JS files in library folder.

inside of **component_1** I have a Layout with ref `myLayout`,
one of those JS files `myLayoutHandler` manipulate `myLayout` (animate it or other stuffs) , when this JS file runs inside **component_1** it works. ( it uses : `this.$refs.myLayout.nativeView` **and this is my problem** ) but when it runs inside other components due to the `this.$refs.` it will not find the `myLayout`.

So how can I access `myLayout` all over the app? Is there something like: *global.$refs*, or  some method like *getElementbyId*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may always use the {N} way of identifying elements. Use `id` instead of `ref` and call [getViewById(yourId)](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page#getviewbyid) on the `Page` instance.

The current page can always be accessed from any element Or [frame](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_frame_.frame).

**Edit:**

If you prefer Vue way of accessing still, you may use [$root or $parent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance), but for every parent above the current component, you will have to chain them.